# Recover secret $x$ when $c\equiv m^x \pmod p$ with public $p$ (modified)

Tags: discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic, chosen-plaintext-attack, known-plaintext-attack

Given an encryption system where $c\equiv m^x \pmod p$, $p$ is a known prime,
1. Is it possible to recover $x$ with a known plaintext attack? Given $(p,\text{factorization of }\varphi(p),m,c)$
2. Is it possible to recover $x$ with a chosen plaintext attack? (Somehow with the chinese remainder theorem on the factorization of $\varphi(p)$ comes to mind)

Comment: Yes fgrieu are right.

Comment: Hint: that's an (imprecise) statement of the [Discrete Logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). Depending on parameters (including the domain for $x$, $p$, its size, the smoothness of $p-1$, the choice of $m$), that's hard, or feasible.

Comment: Hint: you want to consider the [Pohlig-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm).

Comment: Note that $\varphi(p)$ very well can be $\varphi(p)=2q+1, q\in\mathbb P$ rendering this problem really hard.